# Substituição em um texto por palavras de outro arquivo

Tags: r, arquivo, texto

deve ser fácil isso, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar solução! É o seguinte:

Arquivo1 - com textos:

```
Doc    Texto
doc1   Isto é um teste para substituições de palavras.
doc2   As casas são parecidas.
```

Arquivo2 - Referência:

```
Termo          Termo_pai
é              ser
substituições  substituição
palavras       palavra
as             a
casas          casa
são            ser
parecidas      parecida
```

Como faço para substituir as palavras do Arquivo1 pelas palavras que forem encontradas no Arquivo2 na coluna "Termo" pela coluna "Termo_pai"?

O resultado seria:

Arquivo1:

Doc    Texto

doc1   Isto **ser** um teste para **substituição** de **palavra**.

doc2   **A** **casa** **ser** **parecida**.

Ou seja, as palavras em negrito, do Arquivo1, foram encontradas no Arquivo2 na coluna "Termo" e substituídas pelas palavras que estão na coluna "Termo_pai".

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Só com R base pode ser feito do seguinte modo.

```
pat <- paste0("\\b", Arquivo2$Termo, "\\b")
for(i in seq_along(pat))
  Arquivo1$Texto <- gsub(pat[i], Arquivo2$Termo_pai[i], Arquivo1$Texto)

Arquivo1
#   Doc                                           Texto
#1 doc1 Isto ser um teste para substituição de palavra.
#2 doc2                           As casa ser parecida.
```

**DADOS.**

```
Arquivo1 <- read.table(text = "
Doc    'Texto'
doc1   'Isto é um teste para substituições de palavras.'
doc2   'As casas são parecidas.'
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Arquivo2 <- read.table(text = "
Termo          Termo_pai
é              ser
substituições  substituição
palavras       palavra
as             a
casas          casa
são            ser
parecidas      parecida
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Obrigado @Rui Barradas! Fiz o teste com o exemplo e funciona, mas quando aplico o meu "Arquivo2" com 88mil registros, demora bastante e não vejo as alterações. O arquivo é um dataframe. O que será que pode ser?

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução seria utilizar o pacote **stringr**

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Arquivo1 <- read.table(text = "
                       Doc    'Texto'
                       doc1   'Isto é um teste para substituições de palavras.'
                       doc2   'As casas são parecidas.'
                       ", header = TRUE)

Arquivo2 <- read.table(text = "
                       Termo          Termo_pai
                       é              ser
                       substituições  substituição
                       palavras       palavra
                       as             a
                       casas          casa
                       são            ser
                       parecidas      parecida
                       ", header = TRUE)


library(stringr)

for (i in 1:nrow(Arquivo1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(Arquivo2)){
   x = str_replace_all(string = str_extract_all(Arquivo1$Texto[i], "\\w+")[[1]],
                    pattern = paste0("\\b", Arquivo2$Termo[j], "\\b"),
                    replacement = Arquivo2$Termo_pai[j])
   Arquivo1$Texto[i] = paste(x, collapse=" ")
  }
}

Arquivo1
#   Doc                                           Texto
#1 doc1 Isto ser um teste para substituição de palavra.
#2 doc2                           As casa ser parecida.
```

Comment: Obrigado @Fernandes! Fiz o teste com o exemplo e funciona, mas quando aplico o meu "Arquivo2" com 88mil registros, demora bastante e não vejo as alterações. O arquivo é um dataframe. O que será que pode ser?

Comment: Infelizmente essa reposta não tenho, só tendo sua base de dados em mãos para poder avaliar o que procede. Faça um dput do seu dataframe, e poste a saída, talvez possamos ajudar.

Comment: Como fazer um dput?

Comment: Use esse comando: dput(Arquivo2)

Comment: acho que não dá para postar aqui, por que o arquivo tem 800 mil observações. Posso compartilhar num dropbox, pode ser?

Comment: Desconheço as regras do site quanto a isso.